# Convert multiple columned dataframe to 3D matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe similar to the one below:

```
trial Card1_colour Card1_number Card1_shape Card2_colour Card2_number Card2_shape  ......
1        1                1           0           0           1            1
2        0                0           0           1           1            1
3        1                0           0           0           0            0
4        0                0           1           0           0            1
5        1                1           1           1           0            1
.
.
.
.
```

Except my actual dataframe has 12 'Card' variables, Card1_colour : Card4_shape.

```
#Code for generating example data

data<-matrix(rbinom(20*12, 1, .5), ncol=12)
trial<-seq(from = 1, to = 20)

data<-cbind(trial,data)
data<-as.data.frame(data)

colnames(data)[2] <- "Card1_colour"
colnames(data)[3] <- "Card1_number"
colnames(data)[4] <- "Card1_shape"
colnames(data)[5] <- "Card2_colour"
colnames(data)[6] <- "Card2_number"
colnames(data)[7] <- "Card2_shape"
colnames(data)[8] <- "Card3_colour"
colnames(data)[9] <- "Card3_number"
colnames(data)[10] <- "Card3_shape"
colnames(data)[11] <- "Card4_colour"
colnames(data)[12] <- "Card4_number"
colnames(data)[13] <- "Card4_shape"
```

I want to reshape my data into an n(trial) x 4 x 3 matrix that would look something like this:

```
trial Card Colour Number Shape
1      1     1      1      0
1      2     0      1      1
1      3     0      1      0
1      4     1      1      1
2      1     1      0      0
2      2     1      1      0
2      3     0      1      1
2      4     1      1      0
```

In other words, card 1 - card 4 per trial would become row variables, while colour, shape, and number remain column variables.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols = -trial, 
                    names_to = c('Card', '.value'), 
                    names_pattern = 'Card(\\d+)_(.*)')

# A tibble: 80 x 5
#   trial Card  colour number shape
#   <int> <chr>  <int>  <int> <int>
# 1     1 1          0      1     1
# 2     1 2          0      1     1
# 3     1 3          0      0     0
# 4     1 4          0      0     0
# 5     2 1          1      0     1
# 6     2 2          0      1     0
# 7     2 3          1      0     1
# 8     2 4          0      1     0
# 9     3 1          0      1     1
#10     3 2          0      1     1
# … with 70 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `names_sep` with `names_prefix`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(data, cols = -trial, names_to = c('Card', '.value'), 
        names_prefix='Card', names_sep='_')
# A tibble: 80 x 5
#   trial Card  colour number shape
#   <int> <chr>  <int>  <int> <int>
# 1     1 1          0      0     1
# 2     1 2          0      0     0
# 3     1 3          1      0     1
# 4     1 4          1      0     1
# 5     2 1          0      1     1
# 6     2 2          0      0     1
# 7     2 3          0      1     0
# 8     2 4          1      0     1
# 9     3 1          1      1     1
#10     3 2          1      1     0
# … with 70 more rows
```